# What is the difference between pending callbacks phase and poll phase

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to understand event loop of node.js better I went to the node.js documentation. And what did I see:

- **pending callbacks**: executes I/O callbacks deferred to the next loop iteration.
- **poll**: retrieve new I/O events; execute I/O related callbacks (almost all with the exception of close callbacks, the ones scheduled by timers, and setImmediate()); node will block here when appropriate.

So, I need examples when one case will difference of another, because formulation of both phases is "executes I/O callbacks"

Comment: The pending-callbacks phase only executes **deferred** callbacks, whereas the poll-phase will execute non-deferred callbacks.

Comment: @Dai well, what about different events callbacks (`data`, `open`, `end`, `connection`, etc)?

Comment: Those **all** look like I/O callbacks, so they would be executed in the _poll_ phase, unless deferred.

Comment: @Dai how should I understand that they are deffered?

Comment: I believe that's an internal implementation detail, it isn't exposed to user code in NodeJS (IIRC/AFAIK).

Comment: @Dai anyway thanks for that you did less blurry my understanding about event loop.